# how to embed SWT browser in swing jframe

Tags: java, swing, browser, swt, java-canvas

I want to embed my SWT browser in swing jframe.
I try [sample](https://gist.github.com/caprica/6890618), but it need to resize the window to load browser window.
what can I do to repaint the canvas, with out resizing?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? What's the requirement? Why not use any of the Swing alternatives?

Comment: I want to load my html page in my java desktop application and execute my javascript code on it. I found a browser class, it is good but it is behind the jframe which call it, and also I cant do any thing in other open jframe while the browser window is open

Comment: So why not use any of the Swing alternatives?

Comment: which alternatives you recommend?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/145863/best-java-swing-browser-component

Answer (score 8):

Here is a working example on GIT showing how to embed SWT in a traditional Swing JPanel:
https://gist.github.com/caprica/6890618 (Text version: [here](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/caprica/6890618/raw/d89b6d9442b29cd454dcdd275437127f6ff5a1f1/SwtBrowserCanvas.java))

The trick is to create a `java.awt.Canvas` linked to an SWT shell. This canvas can be added to any tradionnal Swing component. The SWT shell loop is managed by a separate thread.

Here is a screenshot on my Windows 7 box with Java 7:
[image]

Comment: djbrowser i a better solution i think,it wrapps the swt stuff and code becomes readable and manageable. You don have to deal with SWT shells etc.

Comment: @benchpresser Can you post some sample code in a response?

Comment: The example does work on Windows 7 with Java6, but the same problem occurs as the OP mentioned. You have to resize the frame before anything is visible