# How to add org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell to a JPanel

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans

How to add a Shell to a jPanel. I created a shell with components and now I want to add it to a jPanel called jPanel1. How can I do this?

```
private Shell sShell = null;
sShell = new Shell();
```

Comment: JPanel is Swing which is a different UI from SWT, mixing SWT and Swing is very difficult. Stick to one GUI system - choose either Swing or SWT (or JavaFX).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the [Eclipse Standard Widget Toolkit (SWT)](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/) a Shell ([`org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell`](https://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Shell.html)) represents a window, whereas a JPanel ([`javax.swing.JPanel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/JPanel.html)) represents only a container in the [Java Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/package-summary.html) GUI widget toolkit.

Therefore **it is not possible to add a `org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell` to a `javax.swing.JPanel`**.

It is not recommended to mix different GUI widget toolkits. There are only rare cases where this make sense (e. g. [using a SWT browser widget in Swing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24782509/6505250)). If you want to use Swing, see e. g. [*Lesson: Getting Started with Swing*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/start/index.html), if you want to use SWT, [these SWT snippets](https://www.eclipse.org/swt/snippets/) might be helpful.

  -